# How to create active buttons in css3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im using the following code for some buttons. But I want as from beginning one of them to be active and when I click on other to become inactive and the new button to be active.

CSS

```
#button-switch
{
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 106px;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
}
#button-switch:active
{
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 106px;
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
}
```

HTML

```
<input id="button-switch" class="first" name="pic0" type="button" value="" onclick="pic0()" style="background-image: url(img/colors/grey.png); "/>

<input id="button-switch" class="first" name="pic1" type="button" value="" onclick="pic1()" style="background-image: url(img/colors/blue.png); "/>
```

JS

```
function pic0()
        {
            document.getElementById("img").src = "img/cars/grey.jpg";
            $('#carTitle').text('Grey').css("color", "#023042");
            $('#carCopy').text('tech').css("color", "#5e686d");
        }
        function pic1()
        {
            document.getElementById("img").src = "img/cars/blue.jpg";
            $('#carTitle').text('Blue').css("color", "#419dda");
            $('#carCopy').text('tech').css("color", "#5e686d");
        }
```

Comment: You cannot use same ids for different elements `button-switch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per valid markup writing you should not use same ids for multiple elements in a single document. So you can change a little like this:

```
<input class="button-switch first" name="pic0" type="button" value="Switch button" />
<input class="button-switch first" name="pic1" type="button" value="Switch button" />
```

and changed a css class this way:

```
.button-switch.active {
  border-radius: 106px;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  background:blue;
  color:white;
}
```

i used it as a class names instead and i would like to write unobtrusive javascript instead so used this:

```
$('.button-switch').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.button-switch.first').removeClass('active');
});
```

```js
$('.button-switch').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.button-switch.first').removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.button-switch {
      border-radius: 106px;
      height: 70px;
      width: 70px;
    }
    .button-switch.active {
      border-radius: 106px;
      height: 90px;
      width: 90px;
      background:blue;
      color:white;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input class="button-switch first" name="pic0" type="button" value="Switch button" />

<input class="button-switch first" name="pic1" type="button" value="Switch button" />
```